# Introduce pop up message when macros execution is complete

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Below is current VBA instructions. Would like to add a message at end to let user know when macro is done such as "Done" , "complete" or "Now please go to step 3"

```
Sub FORMULA_to_value() 
' 
' FORMULA_to_value Macro '

' If MsgBox("Are you sure testing is complete because you can not undo this action?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit

dim MyAddr as string
MyAddr = activesheet.range("D2:D" & Activesheet.cells(rows.count, 4).end(xlup).row).address
```

Comment: @PeterH thank you very much. That works .

Comment: No probs, welcome to SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `MsgBox("Complete")` would do it.

Comment: Note that the parentheses are redundant and that the VBE would render them as `MsgBox ("Complete")`, and that space between `MsgBox` and the `(` character is your hint that everything in parentheses is really just wrapping the 1st argument into an expression that will be evaluated before *its result* is passed to the function. If you mean to pass the *string literal* value `"Complete"`, it should be `MsgBox "Complete"`

Comment: thanks @MathieuGuindon I didn't realise the parenthesis were not needed

Comment: @PeterH thank you 

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks 